# Xcode hangs when working on storyboard for some project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

My Storyboard hangs for a project.while it's working fine for other project.

In this project i working on ipad view on landscape view.in other project working on iphone view.

How can resolve this issue of storyboard ,please guide me.

Comment: What does "hangs" mean? Do you mean you can't open the storyboard for editing? If so, file a bug with Apple, please, sending the project along; they want to know about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when a storyboard contains too much view and subviews or have too much segues and connections between viewcontrollers. You have to be patient and let Xcode load storyboard. then [Refactor your huge storyboard](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/refactoring-with-storyboard-references/) into smaller storyboards.

**Note**: Commenting out any `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` tags in your code will reduce storyboard load time.